# What's a program in mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, research

I don't know if it was asked here, and it is only a curiosity that can be solved by professors or people knowing such projects in universities or mathematical communities.

When I've heard or read the words *Langlands program*, or the *Erlangen program*, I think (for the second one that I know its mathematical meaning,  [Wikipedia tell us that is a method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program)) that is a project with the purpose to finish an unsolved problem or do a task that need many professors working in it.

> **Question.** What's a program in mathematics? For example, currently what's mean a program and what are its characteristics? How do you describe to someone what's a program, its resources, its purpose...? What's it importance (when such project can be called a program?) Are more common in any subject of mathematics? Is it possible to say when (why) the mathematical community will accept such project as a program? **Many thanks.**

I am asking from a divulgative viewpoint. You can add an example, of a program, to illustrate its characteristics.

Comment: If it is a good question, I am waiting an explanation of the generalities  answering what is a program in mathematics. My english was bad, I hope that it is enough understandable.

Comment: Many thanks for your information about the Langland program, now I am unable to understand it. I hope that some user answer the question with an explanation if my intuition is true: many professors try solve or determine an unsolved problem, and the questions that I've asked. Thanks for your attention @user1952009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Langland program is pictured here : http://www.lmfdb.org/universe

It is a list of conjectures (that are known to be true in many special cases) together with a very deep theoretical foundation.

If proven, it would explain how the mentioned objects (*) are related together, and would tell us much on what's necessary and sufficient for generalizing things as the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis#Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis_.28GRH.29) or the [BSD conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture).

(*) $\scriptstyle \text{those objects are amazing because they are related with almost everything in modern mathematics}$

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution and enthusiasm about mathematics (*).